# Remove rows with leading and lagging nulls by group in SQL

Tags: sql, subquery, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, window-functions, sql-delete

I have a dataset like this:

| Date | Account | Spend |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/2/21 | A | null |
| 1/3/21 | A | null |
| 1/4/21 | A | 4 |
| 1/5/21 | A | 6 |
| 1/6/21 | A | null |
| 1/7/21 | A | 7 |
| 1/8/21 | A | null |
| 1/2/21 | B | null |
| 1/3/21 | B | 4 |
| 1/4/21 | B | null |
| 1/5/21 | B | 7 |
| 1/6/21 | B | null |

I want to trim any leading and lagging nulls by group but keep the nulls where there is a value both before and after. The final dataset would look like this:

| Date | Account | Spend |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/4/21 | A | 4 |
| 1/5/21 | A | 6 |
| 1/6/21 | A | null |
| 1/7/21 | A | 7 |
| 1/3/21 | B | 4 |
| 1/4/21 | B | null |
| 1/5/21 | B | 7 |

How can I do this with SQL (specifically Snowflake SQL)?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the basic idea here is to check before and after values in case a given spend column value is NULL. If so, delete it.

To check before and after we have window functions `lead` and `lag`; however, we cannot use them in where clause and so cannot build a straight delete.

Here's my take on it -

```
delete from yourtable a where exists 
    (select * from 
        (select date1, account, spend,
        case 
            when spend is null AND (lag(spend) over (order by 0) is null
            OR
            lead(spend) over (order by 0) is null) 
            then 0 else 1
        end testcol
        from yourtable 
        ) as x
    where
        x.date1 = a.date1
        and x.account = a.account 
        and coalesce(x.spend,0) = coalesce(a.spend,0)
        and x.testcol=0
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can identify the offending rows with `lag`, `lead` and conditional logic; the following query evits them from the result set:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*,
        lead(spend) over(partition by account order by date) lead_spend,
        lag(spend) over(partition by account order by date) lag_spend
    from mytable t
) t
where spend is not null or coalesce(lead_sped, lag_spend) is not null
```

In Snowflake we might be able to express this with [the `qualify` clause](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/qualify.html):

```
select *
from mytable
qualify 
    spend is not null
    or coalesce(
        lead(spend) over(partition by account order by date),
        lag (spend) over(partition by account order by date)
    ) is not null
```

If you want to actually `delete` the rows from the table, I would recommend [the `using` clause](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/delete.html). Assuming that `(date, account)` can be used as a unique key:

```
delete from mytable t
using (
    select *
    from mytable
    qualify 
        spend is null
        and (
               lead(spend) over(partition by account order by date) is null
            or lag (spend) over(partition by account order by date) is null
        )
) x
where x.date = t.date and x.account = t.account
```